# efficient calculation of out-degree in an undirected graph

Tags: python, graph, complexity-theory

I am computing the out-degree of an undirected graph where the nodes are represented as set of variables and 2 nodes are connected if they share at least one variable.

```
def computeOutDegree(self):
    self.nodeOutDegrees = [0] * len(self.nodes)
    for i in range(len(self.nodes)-1):
        setOfVariablesInI = set([elem[0] for elem in self.nodes[i] ])
        for j in range(i+1,len(self.nodes)):
            setOfVariablesInJ = set([elem[0] for elem in self.nodes[j] ])
            if setOfVariablesInI.intersection(setOfVariablesInJ):
                self.nodeOutDegrees[i] += 1
                self.nodeOutDegrees[j] += 1
```

Unfortunately, it is not very efficient with O((N*(N-1))/2). Is there a better way to do so?

Maybe with multi-threading. but where to cut in pieces? Also, += is not atomic, right?

Comment: I would build a (temporary) different datastructure that is more up to the task. e.g. a dict that maps variables to nodes or whatever.

Comment: I'm with syntonym.  You should build an "actual" graph structure and then use the structure of the graph to compute these things efficiently. So for example have a `dict` mapping nodes to list of nodes. Each node has its label attached. BTW: *building* such a structure will always cost O(N^2) for the simple fact that the graph *by definition* has size O(N^2).However using a graph structure you pay for this only when building the graph and then *all* operations can exploit the structure to become more efficient.

Comment: BTW: one small thing about your code. There's no point in using list-comprehensions if yuo are giving them immediately as argument to `set`. So you should replace `set([elem[0] ...])` with just `set(elem[0] ... )`. Otherwise you are looping *twice* over the elements of `self.nodes[i]`, one for building the list and the second time for building the `set`.

Comment: okay, thanks. So i would end up with N^2 for building the graph. Is there a cool python method to build graphs in parallel?